# PHP: Getting work days and closed days based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

So This is what i have done till now ,but i can't think of a way to get the data, entered or checked by user for each day in php . Since i have the same name for all the input type for workdays i.e. name='work' . I cant find a way to get the values for each day seperately( USING PHP).

```
<body>
    <center>
        <form method="post" action="Acharges.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="day" /><b>All Day</b></td>
                    <td><b>Working</b></td>
                    <td><b>Close</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Monday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="mday" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tday" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="wday" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Thursday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="thday" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Friday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="fday" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Saturday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="sday" value="close" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Sunday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="suday" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <b>Number Of Employees:</b><input type="number" max="20"    min="1" name="noe" placeholder="1 - 20" /> <br /> <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Buisness Details:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="doe"
                        placeholder="Date Of Establishment" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="a_tover" placeholder="ANNUAL TURNOVER" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
    <script language="javascript">
        function toggle(source) {
            checkbox = document.getElementsByName('work');
            for (var i = 0, n = checkbox.length; i < n; i++) {
                checkbox[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use arrays in input name like work[Monday], work[Tuesday]. But if u save it in DB you have to work with it to save it in another format, because you can not save arrays in DB directly

Comment: Thanks for quick response @mamosek but i want something less complicated if possible, maybe without array

Comment: You wan to get these value using JS or PHP?

Comment: using php @d.coder

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var workdays=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        var days=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
        var allcheckbox = document.getElementsByName('work');

        function checkcheckbox(arr,checked){    
            for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
                if(checked[i].checked){
                    arr[i]=1;
                }else{
                    arr[i]=0;
                }
            }
            console.log(arr);
        }

        function print(arr,days){
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(arr[i]==0){
                    console.log(days[i]+": close");
                }else{
                    console.log(days[i]+": workday");
                }
            }
        }

        function toggle(source) {
            checkbox = document.getElementsByName('work');
            for (var i = 0, n = checkbox.length; i < n; i++) {
                checkbox[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form method="post" action="Acharges.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="day" /><b>All Day</b></td>
                    <td><b>Working</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Monday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Thursday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Friday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Saturday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><b>Sunday</b></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="work" value="work" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="SEND" onclick="checkcheckbox(workdays,allcheckbox)"/>
            <input type="button" value="SEND" onclick="print(workdays,days)"/>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```